# Prove that the roots of the equation cannot be expressed explicitly

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, galois-theory

I solved the equation
$$x^4-x^3-6x+4+2\sqrt{x^6-x+1}=0$$

I didn’t find another way, I built it into a square
$$x^8-2x^7-3x^6-12x^5+20x^4-8x^3+36x^2-44x+12=0$$
$$(x-1)^2(x^6-4x^4-20x^3-16x^2-20x+12)=0$$

I can't figure out how, using the Galois group $S_6$, to prove that the roots of the sixth degree equation cannot be expressed explicitly?

---

[Edit]: How to show that $x=1$ is the only real solution? From looking at the plot it seems clear that we have $\ge$ for all real values of $x$, and an equality only at $x=1$. It also looks like the function is increasing in $[1,\infty)$ and decreasing in $(-\infty,1]$, but the derivative is a bit cumbersome to manage.
[/Edit, JL]

Comment: Take care : beside the double root $x=1$, the original equation has two complex conjugated roots while the sextic has two real roots and four complex roots.

Comment: How do I prove that the original equation has a single root?

Comment: I suppose that this is the problem.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%3D2sqrt%28x%5E6-x%2B1%29+and+y%3D-x%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2B6x-4

Comment: Okay, thanks, I can use wolfram too. Can you do it with pens on paper? What is the point of sending calculator solutions? Will this solve the problem?

Comment: Are you only interested in the real solutions of the first equation (with the square root)? Looks like $x=1$ is the only such solution as the other roots of the sextic are either complex or correspond to the minus sign of the square root. I didn't check it fully, but it does look like that sextic has Galois group $S_6$ (or at the very least a non-solvable subgroup). What that means is that there is no formula based on basic arithmetic and extracting roots only.

Comment: If you only want to show that $x=1$ is the only real solution, then other methods may work better.

Comment: Yes, I want to show that $x=1$ is the only root of the equation. Can you show me the best way to prove it?

Comment: Methods from calculus are often better for proving such things. I took a quick look, but didn't see an argument. Some rather careful estimates may be needed. I will edit the question to match what you seem to try to do. Please check (and roll it back if I misinterpreted something).

Comment: @Partim did the answer I gave below work for you as to why $x=1$ is the unique real root?

Answer (score -1):

To show the only real root of the original equation is $1$, it's easiest not to go straight to clearing the square root.

We have $f(x)=g(x)$, where
$$f(x)=2\sqrt{x^6-x+1},\quad g(x)=-x^4+x^3+6x-4$$

Note that $f$ is real for all real $x$ and is always positive. $g$ is a quartic with negative discriminant, meaning it has exactly two real roots. One of these is at $x=2$; the other is around $x=0.65$. The leading coefficient of $g$ is also negative; so $g(x)$ is only positive between these two values.

Hence any real roots of the original equation lie in the interval $0.65<x<2$.

At this point you can use the squared form; since
$$x^8-2x^7-3x^6-12x^5+20x^4-8x^3+36x^2-44x+12=(x - 1)^2 \left(x^6 - 4 x^4 - 20 x^3 - 16 x^2 - 20 x + 12\right)$$

it's enough to show that
$$p(x)=x^6 - 4 x^4 - 20 x^3 - 16 x^2 - 20 x + 12 = 0$$

has no real roots in $0.65<x<2$. This isn't too hard to prove; just note that $p$ is negative at the endpoints of the interval and that $p'$ has a unique real root around $x=2.7$, so $p$ is negative on the whole interval.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Some feedback would be useful.